# Como saber a orientação da tela?

Tags: java, android

Qual código que percebe e retorna a orientação da tela?

Se o celular esta em pé ou deitado ?

Answer (score 5):

```
Configuration configuration = getResources().getConfiguration();

    if (configuration.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
        //...
    }else{ 
        //...
    }
```

Nesse exemplo, ele verifica se a posição da tela é landscape (deitado) se não, só pode estar em portrait (em pé)!

Bem simples.

Answer (score 2):

Para verificar orientação basta você usar este código:

```
getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
```

Existe um retorno para cada tipo de orientação, que você pode conferir abaixo:

- `ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED` = 0
- `ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT`  = 1
- `ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE` = 2
- `ORIENTATION_SQUARE`    = 3

#### Detalhes

- [Android Configuration](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#orientation)